# YouTube embed setup without controls but with fullscreen

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube, youtube-api

I need to embed a YouTube player with the following attributes:

- Must not allow users to go forward or back (no progress bar)
- Must have access to player events (player disappears and message is displayed when video ends)
- Must be able to go fullscreen and back to normal at user's request.

I was hoping the JS API would allow me to do this easily, but apparently Flash security makes it so the user has to click somewhere within the flash element itself in order to use Flash to go fullscreen.

As a workaround, right now I'm using the HTML5 fullscreen API as seen here: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/full-screen/index.html

But this causes cross-browser funkiness and even appears to be messing with my player events (the video stops playing and goes back to the beginning when I requestFullScreen).  I could try to work this angle some more but I'm praying there's an easier way.

I would love if there was some way to customize the embedded YouTube player to remove the progress bar but still allow fullscreen w/ Flash, since it's just so much more seamless.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your users should still be able to fullscreen by double clicking the video.  The HTML5 fullscreen api should work fine, but if you're having issues where the flash plugin in re-initializing I would do two things.  First report the bugs to the browser vendors so they can be fixed.  Two listen for onYouTubePlayerReady a second time and add your event listeners again.  Then seek to the point in the video they were at before going fullscreen.